# How can I send an event from a website inside of a webview, to a Nativescript application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript-angular

I have a site built in Angular that a Nativescript (with Angular) calls from inside a webview.

I created a custom event on the Nativescript side (https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-webview-interface), for example:

```
    @ViewChild('web', { static: true }) webRef: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const webview = <WebView>this.webRef.nativeElement;

        webview.on('customEvent', (args: LoadEventData) => {
            alert({
                title: "Success"
            });
        });
    }
```

On the Angular side (the site inside the webview), I am trying to call the "customEvent" this way:

```
  onSubmit(): void {
    const event = new Event('customEvent');
    dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

But the "customEvent" on the Nativescript side doesn't work.
**Is it possible to do this?**

Comment: Please describe in detail what "but it doesn't work" means. Is there an error message? What happens, how does this differ from what you expect? See https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details

Comment: @SherylHohman "the "customEvent" on the Nativescript side doesn't work", when I call the "customEvent" from the Angular side, the event listener from Nativescript side doesn't respond.